# Git branching model implementation

Tags: git

I'm trying to understand how I can impelement the branching model described [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

1. Am I right to infer that on the origin there will be only two branches - master and develop, whereas additional branches like releases, features and hotfixes are created only locally? Or all of these should be created in origin?
2. Could someone please clarify that phrase:

> Each developer pulls and pushes to origin. But besides the centralized
>   push-pull relationships, each developer may also pull changes from
>   other peers to form sub teams...Technically, this means nothing more
>   than that Alice has defined a Git remote, named bob, pointing to Bob’s
>   repository, and vice versa

I'm particularly confused with

> Alice has defined a Git remote, named bob, pointing to Bob’s repository

Where did she define it? On server or locally?

Comment: If you want to implement this branching model, you sure should look at [Git Flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow). It provides git commands that perform the work described in the article.

Comment: Thanks for great suggestion! But since I'm just starting to learn GIT, I want to be able to learn native commands :). Maybe I'll swith to it over time

Answer (score 2):

1. all of them should be created in origin, as any time your colleague might want to help you with the specific branch.
2. If you run git remote command it will shows all your remote repositories. Usually it's only origin there. But you may want to define the repository of other person as your remote repository. More details about remote repositories [here](http://gitref.org/remotes/)

The phrase

> Alice has defined a Git remote, named bob, pointing to Bob’s repository

means, that if Alice now run git remote she will see two repositories: origin and bob. It's because she has previously added a *bob* repository as another remote repository. So now she can share her commits just within this specific repository.